# Label on page html css

Tags: jquery, html, css, label

I try to display message where there is no data so for this first I create label:

```
  <asp:Label ID="Label4"   class="labfour"  runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br /><br />
```

and CSS class

```
.labfour
{
    background-color: #FADBD8;
    color: #E74C3C;
    border-color: #E74C3C;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 320px;
}
```

Then when I build page label is display on page with background color red..

[image]

When I write this `display:none` and  click on button then message not display when I remove this then message is displayed.

So how to hide on page when page is build?

I try to show message through jquery

```
if (myData !== null && Object.keys(myData).length !== 0) {
    strarr = result.d;
    var myarr = strarr;
    Drewchart(myarr);
    $("#tabledata").show();
    $("#container").show();
    $("#<%=Label5.ClientID%>").hide();                    
} else {
    $("#tabledata").hide();
    $("#container").hide();
    $("#cont").hide();
    $("#<%=Label5.ClientID%>").show();
    $("#<%=Label5.ClientID%>").text("DATA NOT FOUND");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So this is how you display message on label and if ur hiding it ofcourse it will hide whole thing as you are using single tag. if you just want to hide message on the label probably use span inside

```css
.labfour{
   background-color: #FADBD8;
    color: #E74C3C;
    border-color: #E74C3C;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 320px;
}
```

```html
<asp:Label ID="Label4"   class="labfour"  runat="server" Text="">Your message here</asp:Label>
```

Comment: but i try to show message through jquery . please check update question

Comment: I don't know what you are really looking at but check this out this might help you, https://jsfiddle.net/Gururaj26/xyoe2nLx/